# Calling constructor of superclass when it doesn't exist

Tags: java, class, subclass, superclass

If I had following question on java theoretical test, what would be the right answer?

The question/task:

Create a Circle class inheriting from the Shape class and call the Shape class constructor in its constructor. Shape class:

```
public class Shape {
    private int size;
}
```

Choose the correct answer:

A:

```
class Circle extends Shape{

    Circle(){
        super();
    }
}
```

B:

> "You can't call constructor of Shape class as it doesn't exist"

Some say that the right answer is B, but I don't understand why it can't be A?
Won't Java create default constructor and call it anyway?

Comment: You only showed us one option, but AFAIK the `Shape` class should have a default constructor, and you should be able to call it.

Comment: Yes it will. Not writing a constructor is the same as having a default empty constructor. There is no such thing as a class without a constructor.

Comment: That being said, there are private constructors. So while there is a way to get that error message (or at least one like it), it won't happen in this case.

Comment: I have to say, this is actually not a terrible question. It's certainly specific, and you've put some effort into trying to understand it. That's often not the case for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official Java Language Specification (JLS), [section 8.8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is implicitly declared.

Reading through that section shows that when `Shape` is compiled, it gets a constructor as if defined by

```
public Shape() {}
```

It is `public` because `Shape` is public and implicitly calls `super();` because it is empty.

So clearly you are correct that option A is the answer.

But what about option B? As it happens, the very next section of the JLS (section [8.8.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.10)) deals exactly with how to create a non-instantiatable class:

> A class can be designed to prevent code outside the class declaration from creating instances of the class by declaring at least one constructor, to prevent the creation of a default constructor, and by declaring all constructors to be `private` ([§6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)).

In practice, if you manually declared a `private` empty constructor to `Shape`, you would not be able to extend it, exactly because the call to `super()` in `Circle` would not resolve:

```
private Shape() {}
```

Comment: If Shape class was private its empty default constructor would be public or private? I tried to run this code: `public class Container {
 
 private class Shape {
  private int size;
 }
 
 class Circle extends Shape{
  
  Circle(){
   super();
  }
 }
 
 public void initCricle(){
  Circle k = new Circle();
  System.out.println("hello");
 }
 
}` and it runs without errors.

Comment: @raporoid. It would be `private`. The access modifier of the constructor is the same as that of the class.

Comment: @raporoid. According to bullet #1 in section 8.8.9: >  The default constructor has the same access modifier as the class, unless the class lacks an access modifier, in which case the default constructor has package access

Comment: So yeah, nesting a private class is another way to trigger the error.

Comment: So if Shape was private, the answer could be B? Ok, thank you :) But.. why then my example works?

Comment: @raporoid. Because members of a class can access each other freely

Comment: So how could I trigger error having private Shape "without" constructor?

Comment: @raporoid. I'm not sure you can.

Answer (score 0):

Option A is the right answer. A class always has the constructor if you have not defined it though java internally defines no argument constructor for it. So for default constructor calling it will not give any error.

I am posting the example which has ran successfully and printed hello on the console.

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

    public Circle() {
        super();
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle circle =  new Circle();
    }
}

public class Shape {
    private int size;
}
```